# Python regular expressions - how to capture multiple groups from a wildcard expression?

Tags: python, regex, lexical-analysis

I have a Python regular expression that contains a group which can occur zero or many times - but when I retrieve the list of groups afterwards, only the last one is present. Example:

`re.search("(\w)*", "abcdefg").groups`()

this returns the list ('g',)

I need it to return ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g',)

Is that possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In addition to [Douglas Leeder's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464736/python-regular-expressions-how-to-capture-multiple-groups-from-a-wildcard-expre#464755), here is the explanation:

In regular expressions the group count is fixed. Placing a quantifier behind a group does not increase group count (imagine all other group indexes increment because an eralier group matched more than once).

Groups with quantifiers are the way of making a complex sub-expression atomic, when there is need to match it more than once. The regex engine has no other way than saving the last match only to the group. In short: There is no way to achieve what you want with a single "unarmed" regular expression, and you have to find another way.

Comment: As an addition: Modern regex implementations like the one in .NET allow you to access previous occurrences of a group besides the last one. Therefore, the above statement is not univerally true, but still holds for the most implementations.

Comment: For the record, there's a regex implementation for Python which also permits access to all of the matches of a capture group: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 40):

```
re.findall(r"\w","abcdefg")
```

Comment: +1: You can't do it with a single regex capture; you have to do it another way.