# Regex question about parsing method signature

Tags: python, regex, method-signature

I'm trying to parse a method signature that is in this format:

```
'function_name(foo=<str>, bar=<array>)'
```

From this, I want the name of the method, and each argument and it's type. Obviously I don't want the `<`, `>` characters, etc. The number of parameters will be variable.

My question is: How is it possible to get all the parameters when using this regex? I'm using Python, but I'm just looking for a general idea. Do I need named groups and, if so, how can I use them to capture multiple parameters, each with it's type, all in one regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't match a variable number of groups with Python regular expressions (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407435/how-do-i-regex-match-with-grouping-with-unknown-number-of-groups)). Instead you can use a combination of regex and `split()`.

```
>>> name, args = re.match(r'(\w+)\((.*)\)', 'function_name(foo=<str>, bar=<array>, baz=<int>)').groups()
>>> args = [re.match(r'(\w+)=<(\w+)>', arg).groups() for arg in args.split(', ')]
>>> name, args
('function_name', [('foo', 'str'), ('bar', 'array'), ('baz', 'int')])
```

This will match a variable number (including 0) arguments. I have chosen not to allow additional whitespace, although you should allow for it by adding `\s+` between identifiers if your format isn't very strict.

Comment: on second thought, that doesn't work. The params part only allows 2 params, no more no less.

Comment: This is the exact problem I had in the first place. I can match multiple of the same pattern with `*`, etc, but I can't capture the multiple values into groups (without manually typing the same group regex 15 times in a row, which wouldn't be very clean at all).

Comment: @orokusaki Okay, seems it's not possible with a single regex. See my new answer, which combines regex with `split()`. It will work for any number, tested it.