# RegEx to remove whitespace from qualified column names in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex

I built a regex to remove whitespace from qualified column names in SQL server. There could be a bunch of these in a single input string For example,

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.[bad column name]
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.[bad column name2]
```

should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.[badcolumnname]
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.[badcolumnname2]
```

Here is the regex search string: `(\[\w*)( )([^\[\]]*?\])`

Regex Replacement: $1$3

But the problem is that it needs to be called many times to replace all the whitespace in a column name.

I.e.

```
[bad column name]
```

Becomes

```
[badcolumn name]
```

Then finally the desired output

```
[badcolumnname]
```

After two successive replacement operations

What is a good way to make this regex so that it does not have to be iterative?

Comment: Always there is three words? `bad`, `column`, `name` ?

Comment: There could be any number of words

Comment: So you are trying to remove all spaces except last one?

Comment: is there a reason why you have to use regex?  if you just want to remove white spaces, can you just do a replace(), which has options to replace occurrences.

Comment: I am trying to remove all whitespace between '[' and ']' brackets

Comment: To give some motivation, the purpose of this is to remove whitespace from bracketed column names in a bunch of sql code

Comment: can you show us your sql statement right now.  thanks

Comment: can you show me the sql statement that you use this (\[\w*)( )([^\[\]]*?\]) with?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you at least knew the maximum number of words in a label you could use replacement such as this

```
\[((\w+)\s?)?((\w+)\s?)?((\w+)\s?)?((\w+)\s?)?((\w+)\s?)?\]

[$2$4$6$8$10]
```

https://regex101.com/r/uB5fQ4/2

If you don't care about the regex being a tiny bit longer, you can use non-capturing groups to avoid capturing the groups you dont need so you dont have to skip them.

```
\[(?:(\w+)\s?)?(?:(\w+)\s?)?(?:(\w+)\s?)?(?:(\w+)\s?)?(?:(\w+)\s?)?\]

[$1$2$3$4$5]
```

https://regex101.com/r/wC1iX2/1

Otherwise you should probably use a parser instead of a regex, since even if you use the global modifier /g each time a match is found the capture group is overwritten.

You can see how that happens here: https://regex101.com/r/iN2rD4/2

Here's one way to achieve the results you want with javascript:

https://jsfiddle.net/yosefh/0ohrno4L/1/

```
<body>
  <div id="result" ></div>
  <script>
  var str = '[bad column name]';
  var result = str.replace(/\s+/g,'');

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  </script>
</body>
```

and in PHP

```
$str = '[bad column name]';
$result = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);
```

You can see options for parsing here

[How do I regex match with grouping with unknown number of groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407435/how-do-i-regex-match-with-grouping-with-unknown-number-of-groups)

and here:

[How to capture an arbitrary number of groups in JavaScript Regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537878/how-to-capture-an-arbitrary-number-of-groups-in-javascript-regexp)

Experiment with regex here: 
https://regex101.com/