# substitution of unknown a priori number of groups - regex python

Tags: python, regex, recursion

Given this string:

```
text = "hello world pattern 24 4 5 this is an example pattern 4 3 11 "
```

I need to substitute  "pattern X Y Z" with "patternX-Y-Z", where X, Y, Z are numbers (no space between "pattern" and the first number).
So far, I'm doing this through this regex :

```
text= re.sub('pattern\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)', r'pattern\1-\2-\3', text).strip()
```

Suppose I have **more than three groups** (something like "pattern 12 3 5 7 5 and pattern 34 5 4") where **the number of groups is not fixed and it is unknown a priori**, how could I write my regex?
Is there a way for writing a recursive regex for substitution?

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407435/how-do-i-regex-match-with-grouping-with-unknown-number-of-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
rx = r'(pattern)(\s*[\d\s]*\d)\b'
s = 'hello world pattern 24 4 5 this is an example pattern 4 3 11 6th oct 2018 pattern 4 3 11 124 2'
print(re.sub(rx, lambda x: "{}{}".format(x.group(1), "-".join(x.group(2).split())), s))
# => hello world pattern24-4-5 this is an example pattern4-3-11 6th oct 2018 pattern4-3-11-124-2
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/aCpNuj)

The `(pattern)(\s*[\d\s]*\d)\b` matches

- `(pattern)` - `pattern` into Group 1
- `(\s*[\d\s]*\d)` - (Group 2) 0+ whitespaces, then 0+ digits and whitespaces and finally a digit
- `\b` - a word boundary

When replacing, the Group 1 value is put at the beginning of the replacement, and Group 2 value is split with whitespace and joined back with `-`.