# python regular expression repeating group matches

Tags: python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python regular expressions - how to capture multiple groups from a wildcard expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464736/python-regular-expressions-how-to-capture-multiple-groups-from-a-wildcard-expr)

I cannot access the group for 3rd or 5th element in the following regex:

```
>>> x = 'f 167 2958 335 3103 0'
>>> re.search('.(\s\d+){5}', x).group()
'f 167 2958 335 3103 0'
>>> re.search('.(\s\d+){5}', x).group(1)
' 0'
>>> # how do i access no 2958 and 3103
```

I know I can achieve the above with pattern = '.\s\d+\s(\d+)\s\d+\s(\d+)\s\d+', but thats lame.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` for this.

```
result = re.findall('\s\d+', x)

print result[1]  # 2958
print result[3]  # 3103
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is a general question then `findall` is your best bet.

If this is the actual thing you are trying to do, `split` would make more sense:

```
>>> x = 'f 167 2958 335 3103 0'
>>> l = x.split()
>>> l[2]
'2958'
>>> l[4]
'3103'
```