# repeated pattern in regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to catch a repeated pattern in my string. The subpattern starts with the beginning of word or `":"` and ends with `":"` or end of word. I tried `findall` and `search` in combination of multiple matching `((subpattern)__(subpattern))+` but was not able what is wrong:

```
cc = "GT__abc23_1231:TF__XYZ451"

import regex
ma = regex.match("(\b|\:)([a-zA-Z]*)__(.*)(:|\b)", cc)
```

Expected output:

```
GT, abc23_1231, TF, XYZ451
```

I saw a bunch of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659068/python-regular-expression-repeating-group-matches), but it did not help.

Comment: In your question code, do you mean `import re`?

Comment: Your  requirements are unclear since the regex you tried contains `__` and matches some letters and `.*` matches anything, 0+ occurrences. Could you please precise? BTW, `_` is a word character, there is no `\b` between `T` and `_`.

Comment: I want to first split on ":", then split on double underscore. I import `regex` as it is recommended in the cited questions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can use

```
(?:[^_:]|(?<!_)_(?!_))+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zS0sV4/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:[^_:]|(?<!_)_(?!_))+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `[^_:]` - any character but `_` and `:`
  - `(?<!_)_(?!_)` - a single `_` not enclosed with other `_`s

[Python demo with `re` based solution](http://ideone.com/quKdB4):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?:[^_:]|(?<!_)_(?!_))+')
s = "GT__abc23_1231:TF__XYZ451"
print(p.findall(s))
# => ['GT', 'abc23_1231', 'TF', 'XYZ451']
```

If the first character is always not a `:` and `_`, you may use [an unrolled regex](https://regex101.com/r/zS0sV4/3) like:

```
r'[^_:]+(?:_(?!_)[^_:]*)*'
```

It won't match the values that start with single `_` though (so, an unrolled regex is safer).

Answer (score 2):

Use the smallest common denominator in *"starts and ends with a `:` or a word-boundary"*, that is the word-boundary *(your substrings are composed with word characters)*:

```
>>> import re
>>> cc = "GT__abc23_1231:TF__XYZ451"
>>> re.findall(r'\b([A-Za-z]+)__(\w+)', cc)
[['GT', 'abc23_1231'], ['TF', 'XYZ451']]
```

Testing if there are `:` around is useless.
*(Note: no need to add a `\b` after `\w+`, since the quantifier is greedy, the word-boundary becomes implicit.)*

---

[EDIT]

According to your comment: *"I want to first split on ":", then split on double underscore."*, perhaps you dont need regex at all:

```
>>> [x.split('__') for x in cc.split(':')]
[['GT', 'abc23_1231'], ['TF', 'XYZ451']]
```