# My re.finditer shows everything when using .group(0), but if I use .group(5) it shows an empty string (python)

Tags: python, regex

I am using this regex patttern in python:

```
'("CDS)(complement)?(\()?(join)?([\(]?[<]?[0-9]{0,6}[.]{0,2}[>]?[0-9]{0,6}[,]?[\)]{0,2})*(/locus_tag=)(["])([^"]*)(["])'
```

To find things in a file, like this:

```
"CDScomplement(join(169314..169361,169451..169552,169635..169690,169833..169937,170056..170125,170277..170518,170640..170841,170968..171090,171191..171263,171387..171508))/locus_tag="MAL1P1.24"
```

But there is something strange, because when I use re.finditer and use a `for` loop and `print(matchobject.group(0))`, I can see that *every matchobject group completely matches* matches. But when I use `print(matchobject.groups())` or `print(matchobject.group(5))` it returns an empty string. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group 5 is that long group with a `*` after it.  This doesn't capture all the repetitions of the group (see [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464736/python-regular-expressions-how-to-capture-multiple-groups-from-a-wildcard-expr) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764930/capturing-repeating-subpatterns-in-python-regex) as well as [info here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)).  Wrap that group in another set of parentheses to capture all the repetitions of the inner group:

```
>>> rx = re.compile(r'("CDS)(complement)?(\()?(join)?(([\(]?[<]?[0-9]{0,6}[.]{0,2}[>]?[0-9]{0,6}[,]?[\)]{0,2})*)(/locus_tag=)(["])([^"]*)(["])')
>>> [m.groups() for m in rx.finditer(txt)]
[(u'"CDS',
  u'complement',
  u'(',
  u'join',
  u'(169314..169361,169451..169552,169635..169690,169833..169937,170056..170125,170277..170518,170640..170841,170968..171090,171191..171263,171387..171508))',
  u'',
  u'/locus_tag=',
  u'"',
  u'MAL1P1.24',
  u'"')]
```