# Regex multiple expression

Tags: python, regex

I've got the following structure:

```
<ins rev="REV-NEU" editindex="0">
    <insacc rev="c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512">eins</insacc>
    <insacc rev="c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512">zwei</insacc>
    <insacc rev="c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512">drei</insacc>
<insacc rev="c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512">vier</insacc>
</ins> 
<del rev="REV-NEU" editindex="1">eins</del> 
<insacc rev="c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512">fünf</insacc>
```

With a regex I want to match the ins-tag with multiple insacc-tags (can be 1 or 20) inside.

I tried it with the following regex, but it only matches the last insacc:

```
<ins rev="[^<]+" editindex="[^<]+">(<(insacc|deldec) rev="[^<]+">([^<]+)</(insacc|deldec)>)+</ins>
```

Comment: Why don't use an `XML parser`, like `xml.etree.ElementTree` from standard library?

Comment: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `lxml` for this.

```
from lxml import etree
xml = etree.fromstring(xml_string)
ins_tags = xml.xpath('//ins[./insacc]')
for ins_tag in ins_tags:
    # do work
```

Isn't is simple?

Comment: Muuuuuch cleaner than any regex I could think of

Answer (score 0):

By all means use `lxml` or `Beautiful Soup` ([see this answer for why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3894453)). Regular expressions cannot really do what you want because group counts are fixed. Here's more information: [an article on repeating groups in regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) and [this SO answer providing an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464736/python-regular-expressions-how-to-capture-multiple-groups-from-a-wildcard-expr?lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

I defy you to reliably or easily do this with a regex:

```
# -*- coding: utf 8 -*- 

import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xml='''\
<data>
<ins rev="REV-NEU" editindex="0">
    <insacc rev="c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512">eins</insacc>
    <insacc rev="c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512">zwei</insacc>
    <insacc rev="c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512">drei</insacc>
<insacc rev="c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512">vier</insacc>
</ins> 
<del rev="REV-NEU" editindex="1">eins</del> 
<insacc rev="c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512">fünf</insacc>
</data>'''      

for child in et.fromstring(xml).iter():
    print child.tag, child.attrib, child.text
```

Prints:

```
data {} 

ins {'editindex': '0', 'rev': 'REV-NEU'} 

insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} eins
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} zwei
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} drei
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} vier
del {'editindex': '1', 'rev': 'REV-NEU'} eins
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} fünf
```

If you just want `./ins/insacc`, use xpath:

```
for child in et.fromstring(xml).findall('./ins/insacc'):
    print child.tag, child.attrib, child.text
```

Prints:

```
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} eins
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} zwei
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} drei
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} vier
```

If you want all `insacc` even at the root:

```
for child in et.fromstring(xml).iter():
    if child.tag=='insacc':
       print child.tag, child.attrib, child.text

insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} eins
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} zwei
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} drei
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} vier
insacc {'rev': 'c3ce7877-42bf-4c41-b3c0-fd225ccaf512'} fünf
```