# Script Header Regex?

Tags: regex

I am attempting to make a regex to recongise a complex script declaration such as:

```
script void bar(type foo, type baz)
```

Where both "type"'s are in the same capture group

currently, I have the Regex:

```
(script)\s(\w*)\s(\w*)\((?:([a-z|A-Z]+)\s\w+)?\)
```

This recognises capture groups, as shown in the link. https://regex101.com/r/nB3oL3/3

1. [0-6]   `script`
2. [7-11]  `void`
3. [12-15] `bar`
4. [16-20] `type`

It also recognises the strings

```
script void bar(type foo)
script void bar()
```

Which is exactly what I want, except for the fact that it will not recognise any additional parameters such as "type baz"

```
script void bar(type foo, type baz)
```

I'm struggling to work out a way of recursively recognising the "type" in

```
", type baz"
```

addition without adding additional capture groups (if this is even possible?). I was also unsure if I needed to use a branch reset for this effect?

As i'm doing this for sublime, I figure it must be using the python regex engine.

Any help would be much appriciated!

- Chris

Comment: **A quick note - ive just noticed that this only recognises lower case, this was not my intention, but easily fixable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an engine that supports recursive regex, `^(script)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\((?:([a-zA-Z]+)\s\w+(?:,\s)?)*\)$` should work, but as taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/464879/4627632) post, recursive implementations is not widely implemented. ( As the comment on this state, there exists for example plug-ins for python to support this. )

Comment: This is good, but seems to only capture the last entered type

Comment: `script void bar(type foo, ` **type**  `baz)` rather than both of them - or is the website an example of the lack of support for recursive regex?

Comment: From what I could infer the website is an example of the lack of support, as soon as I get a chance I will install the python plug-in and try directly in the interpreter.