# perl regex: how to capture multi group use only one express?

Tags: regex, perl

```
Text 1 ： 
do not match: nw, n, s and somethingelse.
all directions are: n, w, s and e.
Expect ：{n, w, s, e}


Text 2 ： 
do not match: nw, n, s and somethingelse.
all directions are: nw, sw, se, w, ..., s and e.
Expect ：{nw, sw, se, w, ..., s, e}
```

Is it possible to capture all directions in one express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible capture in one expression as explained here: [Python regular expressions - how to capture multiple groups from a wildcard expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464736/python-regular-expressions-how-to-capture-multiple-groups-from-a-wildcard-expr#464755)

A soultion to your problem might be this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $text = "all directions are: nw, sw, se, w, ..., s and e.";
my @capture;
if($text =~ s/all directions are: (\w+),\s+(.*)/$2/) {
    push @capture, $1;
    while($text =~ s/(\w+),\s+(.*)/$2/) {
        push @capture, $1;
    }
    if($text =~ /(\w+)\s+and\s+(\w+)\./) {
        push @capture, $1;
        push @capture, $2;
    }
}
print Dumper \@capture;
```

Comment: Thanks. I can use only one regex in case, it sounds a impossible mission.

Comment: Yeah looks like that's not possible. This is more of a parsing problem. You can't do everything with regex.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
my $text = "all directions are: nw, sw, se, w, ..., s and e.";

if( $text =~ /all directions are:\s+(([^,]+,\s+)+)(\w+)\s+and\s+(\w+)\./)
{
    print "$1 $3, $4\n";
}
```

Output: 
`nw, sw, se, w, ...,  s, e`

Explanation:

`([^,]+,\s+)` matches a directory name followed by a comma (`,`) and some spaces. This can repeat `n` number of times in the string.

Then we have to match the `x and y` part. `(\w+)\s+and\s+(\w+)\.` will take care of that.

Comment: Question updated. some conditions missed, it's my bad, sorry.

Comment: Answer Updated. If you just give `all directions are` in the beginning, this will work, right? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

While, as Phyreprooph has explained, it's not possible with a single expression, you could use the `/g` ("global") modifier to match multiple times and yield a list of matches like this:

```
if(/all directions are:\s*(.*)/) {
    @dir = $1 =~ /(\.\.\.|\b[nsew]{1,2}\b)/g;
    print "{", join(", ", @dir), "}\n";
}
```